# Compile Mono project on Windows and run on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I'm trying to figure out how to compile a Mono project (in Xamarin Studio) on Windows and then run the .exe on Linux. So far, I get

```
Cannot open assembly 'Program.exe': File does not contain a valid CIL image.
```

when I try to run the executable on Linux.
I'm compiling with the same commands on Windows as when I compile on Linux, `mcs` and then try to run it with `mono`.
What I'm I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Xamarin is for phones...

Comment: @leppie what? http://www.monodevelop.com/download/

Comment: That is MonoDevelop, not Xamarin Studio

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin Studio is an IDE and when it compiles your application on Windows, it is very likely to use .NET Framework by default and the latest .NET bits (4.5.1 and above) do not yet have counterpart on Mono.

Do install a Linux machine and MonoDevelop on it and that makes sure all bits you compile are working.

Comment: I tried to set the compiler in Xamarin Studio to Mono. See this image: http://i.imgur.com/7PodTNT.png

Comment: @ViggoLundén that's the runtime when debugging but has nothing to do with compiler. You have to change project options.

Comment: I also tried to compile on Windows with `mcs` and then run on Linux, but no luck there either. I will try to change compiler settings when I get home.